# io.on() is not working after using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, server

This is what I am using. io.on() was working fine but after using mongoose.connect(), it's not working anymore. In terminal only showing
`server is running:5000 mongo db connection null` 
Not sure why io.on() is not working.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbUrl = '' //removed db url for security reason.
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended":false}));

let message = []
app.get('/messages',(req,res)=>{
    res.send(message)
})
app.post('/messages',(req,res)=>{
    message.push(req.body)
    io.emit('message',req.body)
    res.sendStatus(200);
})

mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    console.log('mongo db connection', err)
})
io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    console.log("user connected")
})

const server = http.listen(5000,(err)=>{
    if(err){
        console.error();
    }
    console.log("server is running:"+ server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: So when you remove the call to `mongoose.connect()` it's working again?

Comment: @robertklep I am using both of them `mongoose.connect()` and `io.on()`.

Comment: But you're saying that after adding `mongoose.connect()`, `io.on()` stopped working. So when you remove `mongoose.connect()`, does `io.on()` work again?

Comment: @robertklep yes, if I remove `mongoose.connect()` , then it's working.

Comment: This is very likely a local issue, I cannot reproduce it with your exact code, the `io.on()` event handler is working just fine.

Comment: @robertklep  I copied and pasted the same code in a new project folder, but now it's working. I am not sure why it was not working earlier.

Answer (score 0):

[this is my index.js file it's work for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMxfX.png)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I am using mongoose here. This code was working fine but When I added mongoose.connect(), from then  io.on() is not working.

Comment: Code should be available in the answer not in a screenshot @yassine.